# Htaccess - Why isn't this RewriteRule working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a misconfigured URL with a doubleslash followed by a hyphen which I'm trying to redirect. I can't work out why the line below doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^towns//-in-(.*).html$ towns/index.php?old_town=$1 [L]
```

The URL I want to redirect is:
http://www.mywebsite.com/towns//-in-barton.html

When I go to the URI in question I get a 404 error, but the file that it's supposed to be redirecting to definitely exists. And when I type the original URI in there is no redirection in the chain, just a 404...

I have the following rule on the line after in the htaccess for another reason and this rule is working: `RewriteRule ^towns/(.*)/$ towns/index.php?old_town=$1 [L]`

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: browsers may correct doubleslashes so check raw http headers.

Comment: @Deadooshka the reason I'm doing this is because the URL is a 404